# Literature to get started on Pfaffian systems

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, pfaffian

I am getting into Pfaffian systems as a way to represent systems of PDEs. I was wondering what could be a good book to get started. I found some notes and lectures online, but nowhere a clear algorithmic way to take a generic PDE (or a system of PDEs) and convert it into a Pfaffian system. Any help would be appreciated. For background, I have a working knowledge of exterior calculus and coordinate-free tensor calculus.